# Declare AppDelegate the Push Notification delegate from another class in Swift?

Tags: swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am leveraging a singleton of the `Utilities` class to present a popup and request `Push Notifications` access, but I have made the `AppDelegate` class the `delegate` for `FirebaseMessaging` and `UserNotifications` so the `didReceiveRegistrationToken` function never gets called at the time the user has granted access in the sign-up process and thus does not save the token at that time.

I need to make the `AppDelegate` the `delegate` for notifications incase new registration token are received and therefore save it.

**How can I make the `AppDelegate` the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate` and `Messaging.messaging().delegate` from within my Utilities class?**

Declaring an AppDelegate singleton is not allowed.

Utilities Class:

```
Class Utilities {

static let run = Utilities()


    func showNotificationServicesIsDisabledPopup(viewController: UIViewController, handler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){

        //present popup to allow for push notifications...

    }


    func registerForRemoteNotification() {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in

                if error == nil{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() } //
                    //UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

                }//end if

            }//end requestAuthorization

        } else {

            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            //Declaring AppDelegate as the delegate
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = appDelegate
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = appDelegate

        }//end else


    }

}
```

AppDelegate Class:

```
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging





class AppDelegate: UIResponder, MessagingDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate {

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        }

        func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

                let dataDict:[String: Bool] = [fcmToken: true]

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

                DataService.run.saveFCMToken(tokenDict: dataDict, fcmtoken: fcmToken) { (success) in

                    if success {
                        print("FCM Token Saved: \(fcmToken)")
                        DEVICEID_FCMTOKEN = fcmToken
                        self.connectToFCM()
                    }//end if

                }//end saveFCMToken

            }//end func

        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't see where the problem is. Can't you just do  `UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` to get the instance of `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper Is this what you mean? have edited (above) my `Utilities` class to declare an instance of the `AppDelegate` as the `UNUserNotificationCenter` and `Messaging` delegate. Question, would this change result in that the AppDelegate would receive the token via the `didReceiveRegistrationToken` delegate function and therefore process the token as I originally intended?